# Corona SDK how to add custom method to displayobject

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk

I want to add custom method to display object something like the prebuilt methods for example "setFillColor"

i wrote the following code which is not working; however, it explains what i need

```
function display:foo(bar)
    print(bar)
end


local myRectangle = display.newRect( 0, 0, 150, 50 )
myRectangle:foo("something to be printed")
```

i want the "foo" method to be ready for all DisplayObjects not only myRectangle?

Comment: It doesn't work because a `ShapeObject` is returned.

Comment: Are you trying to add a method or replace an existing method with your own?

Comment: @Schollii I wanted a new method like the awesome "Foo" method :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example below. Untested but should work. Then it will be available to all newRect calls. You would have to do this for all display.* calls that you wish to use however

```
local oldNewRect = display.newRect

function display.newRect( ... )
    local rect = oldNewRect( ... )

    function rect:foo( str )
        print( str )
   end

    return rect
end

-- usage

local rect = display.newRect( 0, 0, 40, 40 )
rect:foo( "hello" ) -- prints "hello"
```

Comment: Won't work, as he wants to pass as argument a string

Comment: Yeah. I was showing how to add a function to every display object constructor. Adding the functionality to pass an argument as a string to what I posted above is trivial

Comment: Edited to add the ability to pass in a string and print its value

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not to replace any methods in the library because this means that every object created, not just those you create, are affected, and this could have unintended side effects. So I would advocate simply creating a function that adds the desired method to every instance you create. This method also serves as a signature that this display object is one of "yours" (not one created "behind the scenes" by Corona). For example,

```
function myNewCustomRect(...)
    local obj = display.newRect(...)
    obj.foo = function (self, a,b,c)
        -- self is obj, although obj is an upvalue so can use directly too
        print(self, obj, a,c,b)
    end
    return obj
end

yourRect = myNewCustomRect(0, 0, 150, 50)
yourRect:foo(1,2,3) -- first two data printed should be same
```

Comment: Yeah, this is better than overriding corona's display methods, however he asked for an extension to the display object itself, that's what I show in my example. I agree however that creating your own methods that call corona's internal methods is the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

A bit complicated as we need to hijack the display.newRect call. Here is how to do it:

```
-- Store the old method
local oldNewRect = display.newRect

display.newRect = function(...)
    local oDisplayObject = oldNewRect(...)

    oDisplayObject.foo = function(oDisplayObject, sText)
       -- Do something with the display object
       -- Print the text passed as argument
       print(sText)
    end
    return oDisplayObject
end

local myRectangle1 = display.newRect( 0, 0, 150, 50 )
myRectangle1:foo("something to be printed")

local myRectangle2 = display.newRect( 0, 0, 150, 50 )
myRectangle2:foo("something to be printed")
```

Comment: @PersuitOfPerfection On the other hand, [that](http://codepad.org/GTYR5Tk9) isn't required.

Comment: The `...` ensures that all parameters to the function call are passed on. The colon syntax will work too. There is no requirement for arg name to be `self`.

Comment: Matter of personal preference then i guess. Neater to pass self explicitly imho

Comment: @scholli, that was not what i was saying. I understand how the code works.

Comment: @PersuitOfPerfection Well self is just a construct in Lua. In my case I prefer to use explicitely the .foo = function() notation to clearly explain what's going on since the :foo notation can be confusing sometimes, especially when you hijack method calls, like in this case.

Comment: @Teddy, i'm aware of what self is in Lua ;) Everyone has their own coding style/preferences however.